# Mofifying X-axis unit on Python graphs

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

The following lines:

```
import Quandl
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import data from Quandl
DJI  = Quandl.get("WREN/W6", trim_start="1980-01-01", trim_end= datetime.date.today())

'''
type(DJI)   =>   class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
'''

# Plot DJI
DJI.plot()
plt.show()
```

Produce this chart:

[image]

How can I set the major unit so that each year from the start to the end of my series reads and read only once?

Maybe using MultipleLocator and FormatStrFormatter functions? But how does that work with *dates* ?     The length of my time series my vary.

Comment: You want to show every year on the x axis?

Comment: yes, this is what my blabla above tries to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`YearLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.YearLocator) from matplotlib's `dates` module.

```
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, DateFormatter

...

# YearLocator defaults to a locator at 1st of January every year
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

Comment: thx.  And what is the trick now if I want the the x-axis read 1 year over 2 (1980, 1982, 1984, ...) against every single year (1980, 1981, ...) ???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want a tick at every other year (1980, 1982, 1984), you can specify this with `YearLocator(base=2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to actually call `plt.plot` (or use the `matplotlib` API) since matplotlib doesn't correctly render `datetime64` arrays on the x-axis. For example:

```
In [18]: s = Series(randn(10), index=date_range('1/1/2001', '1/1/2011', freq='A'))

In [19]: s
Out[19]:
2001-12-31   -1.236
2002-12-31    0.234
2003-12-31   -0.858
2004-12-31   -0.472
2005-12-31    1.186
2006-12-31    1.476
2007-12-31    0.212
2008-12-31    0.854
2009-12-31   -0.697
2010-12-31   -1.241
Freq: A-DEC, dtype: float64

In [22]: ax = s.plot()

In [23]: ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())

In [24]: ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

gives

[image]

Instead you should do something like:

```
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.plot(s.index.to_pydatetime(), s.values)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

to get:

[image]

If you want different year multiples, pass the multiple you want to the `YearLocator` constructor, like so:

```
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.plot(s.index.to_pydatetime(), s.values)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

resulting in:

[image]